# gettin checkbox value generated by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a small php code in which on change dropdown . values are fetched from database by ajax call and then are displayed with checkboxes . now since these checkboxes are generated by ajax so i am confused how to get the values of checkboxes on the main file .
simply my questions how to get values of checkboxes that are generated by ajax . 
If someone could help . thanking you in anticipation of your response .

```
<?php

 $id=$_GET["q1"];
$conn=oci_connect("system","ashfaq","localhost/xe");

    $sql=oci_parse($conn,"select item_code, Item_description from pos_item where item_category_id=$id");
ociexecute($sql);
$row=oci_fetch_array($sql);
while($row=oci_fetch_array($sql))
{

echo "<br>";

echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"hob[]\" value=\"\">";
 echo "$row[0] &nbsp; $row[1] ";


}

?>
```

Comment: You get the values the same way you would get the values of any other checkbox. Ajax doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the php page to include script in the response, or deppending your jquery version, delegate code for added checkboxes.

Some versions of jquery use the delegation with `delegate`, others with `on`. The syntax is:

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

$( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});

$( "table" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

Taken from:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/